# Magento 2: Unable to write file into directory

Tags: magento2, error, magento-community, sample-data

After installing Magento 2.4.1 I am getting this error:

```
Exception #0 (DomainException): Unable to write file into directory /var/www/html/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/912eee9e4cfa9553368073a74de060ea/m/b. Access forbidden.
```

I have manually installed the sample data for 2.4.1 version and when clicking on the product detail page, this error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that this directory doesn't have the appropriate permissions.

Try `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/magento2/pub/*`

If that doesn't work, I use this code when all else fails.

Try:

`rm -rf /var/www/html/mage/view_preprocessed/* && rm -rf /var/www/html/mage/pub/static/frontend/* && rm -rf /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/* && bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && bin/magento indexer:reindex && bin/magento cache:flush && chmod -R  777 pub var generated`

If neither work then:

Check your var/log files.

Comment: I did add the right permission to each folder, I tried giving 777  to all the folders but the issue remains there.

Comment: I added a set of commands that I use when all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
Log in to your SSH/CLI with admin permissions and navigate to the root of your store.
Set permissions to the files: find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
Set permissions to the directories: find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
Set permissions to special directories: find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```